# Mecha anime: main character in a black mecha fighting 4 enemies in a school coliseum

Tags: story-identification, anime, mecha

I'm looking for a mecha anime I saw on Facebook today but I forgot to save the video.

You see 5 mecha in a school coliseum, 4-vs-1 I think. The main character is sitting in an "old" black mecha with an red ball (AI)? in the cockpit. The enemies got a newer generation mecha with different colors.

The MC tries to fight with a blade but the AI messed up and he has to fight with a shovel. One of the other mecha was attacking with spears and gets one-hitted with the shovel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is an arc of [*The World of Otome Games is Tough for Mobs*](https://mobuseka.fandom.com/wiki/The_World_of_Otome_Games_is_Tough_for_Mobs_Wiki), specifically [the anime](https://mobuseka.fandom.com/wiki/The_World_of_Otome_Games_is_Tough_for_Mobs_Anime) that came out in April 2022.

> Office worker Leon is reincarnated into a particularly punishing dating sim video game, where women reign supreme and only beautiful men have a seat at the table. But Leon has a secret weapon: he remembers everything from his past life, which includes a complete playthrough of the very game in which he is now trapped. Watch Leon spark a revolution to change this new world in order to fulfill his ultimate desire... of living a quiet, easy life in the countryside!

The mecha is [Arroganz](https://mobuseka.fandom.com/wiki/Arroganz).

[image: Image of Arroganz with shovel]

Found via a search for `mecha anime shovel`

Comment: I realize not entirely covered in my answer, my search led me to a Facebook post about the anime, which made me double sure that it would be the right one for the querent.